# Multi line string containing special characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, processing

I'm trying to use the javascript port of processing found at http://ejohn.org/blog/processingjs/ I want to use the following constructor. `Processing(CanvasElement, "some massive block of code");` I know javascript doesn't natively support multiline strings but is there a way to pass something like the following with out having to concatenate every line and escape every special character?

```
/**
 * Array. 
 * 
 * An array is a list of data. Each piece of data in an array 
 * is identified by an index number representing its position in 
 * the array. Arrays are zero based, which means that the first 
 * element in the array is [0], the second element is [1], and so on. 
 * In this example, an array named "coswav" is created and
 * filled with the cosine values. This data is displayed three 
 * separate ways on the screen.  
 */

size(200, 200);

float[] coswave = new float[width];

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  float amount = map(i, 0, width, 0, PI);
  coswave[i] = abs(cos(amount));
}

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  stroke(coswave[i]*255);
  line(i, 0, i, height/3);
}

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  stroke(coswave[i]*255 / 4);
  line(i, height/3, i, height/3*2);
}

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  stroke(255 - coswave[i]*255);
  line(i, height/3*2, i, height);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript actually does support multi-line strings: append a backslash to the end of each line:

```
alert('1\
    2\
    3');
```

Not very pretty, but it works.

An alternative would be to use a script to encode your text... I'd suggest PHP as it's a 1-liner:

```
<?=json_encode('your text');?>
```

Comment: +1.  And I thought I knew every nuance of Javascript syntax.  Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a more maintainable solution, I would place it in script tags tags in the body of the page, eg:

```
<script type="text/processing" id="code">
/**
 * Array. 
 * ...
 */

size(200, 200);
...
</script>
```

And construct your Processing object like:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var code = document.getElementById('code');
Processing(canvas , code.textContent);
```

For a quick and dirty solution run your processing code through a JSON encoder as [RoBorg suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461015/multi-line-string-containing-special-characters-in-javascript#461039) and you'll get a string that you can just copy and paste into the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Place the "massive block of code" in its own file on the server, fetch with AJAX and ensure it has reasonable cache headers.

Comment: This is a quick and dirty solution to a problem so don't want to go the ajax route if I can avoid it. See this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460085/best-language-for-quickly-creating-user-interfaces-with-out-drag-and-drop

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just put the text in the HTML page (hidden, for example) and get it from there...

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use E4X literals

```
var s = "" + <r><![CDATA[
line 1
line 2
]]></r>;
```

Although I doubt it is supported by IE6.

Comment: It's not even supported by IE7